# How can I import a local module using Databricks asset bundles?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-asset-bundle

I want to do something pretty simple here: import a module from the local filesystem using databricks asset bundles. These are the relevant files:

**databricks.yml**

```yaml
bundle:
  name: my_bundle

workspace:
  host: XXX

targets:
  dev:
    mode: development
    default: true

resources:
  jobs:
    my_job:
      name: my_job
      tasks:
        - task_key: my_task
          existing_cluster_id: YYY
          spark_python_task:
            python_file: src/jobs/bronze/my_script.py
```

**my_script.py**

```py
from src.jobs.common import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world()
```

**common.py**

```py
def hello_world():
    print("hello_world")
```

And the following folder structure:

```
databricks.yml
src/
├── __init__.py
└── jobs
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── bronze
    │   └── my_script.py
    └── common.py
```

I'm deploying this to my workspace + running it by using Databricks CLI v0.206.0 with the following commands:

```
databricks bundle validate
databricks bundle deploy
databricks bundle run my_job
```

I'm getting issues to import my `common.py` module. I'm getting the classic `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` error here.

I've added the `__init__.py` files as I typically do when doing this locally, and tried the following variations:

```
from src.jobs.common import *
from jobs.common import *
from common import *
from ..common import *
```

I guess my issue is that I don't really know what the python path is here, since I'm deploying it on Databricks. How can I do something like this using databricks asset bundles?

Comment: are you deploying this into the workspace, not Repos?

Comment: I've edited my question to contain that info, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into a similar issue, albeit with notebook tasks, and came to the following resolution, adapted to your example file structure:

In your databricks.yml file, pass an argument to your script via parameters:

**databricks.yml**

```yaml
    resources:
      jobs:
        my_job:
          name: my_job
          tasks:
            - task_key: my_task
              existing_cluster_id: YYY
              spark_python_task:
                python_file: src/jobs/bronze/my_script.py
                parameters: ['/Workspace/${workspace.file_path}/src']
```

**main.py**

```py
    import sys
    bundle_src_path = sys.argv[1]
    sys.path.append(bundle_src_path)

    from src.jobs.common import *
```

**Caveats:**

1. As mentioned, I am using a notebook_task which allows me to pass in parameters that I can read using dbutils. I haven't tested the spark_python_task parameters passing above, but it appears similar and may at least be enough to get you into a working state. [Databricks API reference](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/create)
2. The sys path technique is recommended by Databricks [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/workspace-modules.html), though you may need to approach it differently based on your runtime version.
3. This works well for non-production deployment targets. The parameter passed in for [production](https://github.com/databricks/bundle-examples/blob/main/default_python/databricks.yml#L37) would likely need to be modified (though I haven't made it that far myself yet)!

Answer (score 0):

you can use that snippet too, at the beginning of your notebook

```
import os
import sys
# get the current path
notebook_path =  '/Workspace/' + os.path.dirname(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().notebookPath().get())
sys.path.append(notebook_path)
```